# counting simple numbers in bash - error

Tags: bash

I don't see the mistake, do you? Thanks

```
#!/bin/sh

count=0
while [ $count −lt 3 ]
do
    sleep 1
    count=$(($count + 1))
    echo $count
done
```

Output:

```
./RestartProcessProgram.sh: 4: [: 0: unexpected operator
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ charinfo '−'
U+2212 MINUS SIGN [Sm]
```

Try using "-" instead.

```
$ charinfo '-'
U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS [Pd]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't write that code myself, had to copy it so I assumed it was correct.

Comment: Translation: the `[ $count −lt 3 ]` syntax is using a different hyphen. Just change it to the normal one (slightly shorter).

Comment: @Ni3l5 did you copy it out of a document with formatted text by any chance? If so, that could explain how it was changed.

Comment: `charinfo: command not found` Where did you get this command? Not available on ubuntu repositories... Looks like a useful command to have... :)

Comment: @anishsane: I wrote it. It uses Python's `unicodedata` module to give information about each character in the string passed as the first argument.